# Find differences between two directories

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

Coming from another language than Python, I would like to see if my code is "pythonic" enough and follows good practices.

It compares two directories, showing all files that are in one and not in the other. Moreover, you can add up to two options:

- a to also compare the content of the files
- s to save the results into a file

Note: this is in Python 2.7, and I don't have access to `argparse`.

```
import filecmp
import os.path
import sys

def print_help():
    print "Use : python cmp_dir.py <dir_1> <dir_2> [-a] [-s <file>]"
    print "dir_1 and dir_2 : directories to compare"
    print "-a : also compare data inside files"
    print "-s : save results inside <file>"
    sys.exit()
    
def show_diff_in_dir(dir_name, list_diff, file_to_save_results):
    msg = "files or subdirs only in %s : %s " % (dir_name, list_diff)
    if file_to_save_results:
        file_to_save_results.write(msg + "\n")
    else:
        print msg
        
def show_diff_in_files(dir_name, diff_files, file_to_save_results):
    msg = "different files in %s : %s " % (dir_name, diff_files)
    if file_to_save_results:
        file_to_save_results.write(msg + "\n")
    else:
        print msg
        
def compare_dir_trees(dir1, dir2, compare_file_data, file_to_save_results):
    dirs_cmp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    
    if dirs_cmp.left_only:
        show_diff_in_dir(dir1, dirs_cmp.left_only, file_to_save_results)
    if dirs_cmp.right_only:
        show_diff_in_dir(dir2, dirs_cmp.right_only, file_to_save_results)
    if compare_file_data and dirs_cmp.diff_files:
        show_diff_in_files(dir1, dirs_cmp.diff_files, file_to_save_results)
        
    for common_dir in dirs_cmp.common_dir:
        new_dir1 = os.path.join(dir1, common_dir)
        new_dir2 = os.path.join(dir2, common_dir)
        compare_dir_trees(new_dir1, new_dir2, compare_file_data, file_to_save_results)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    compare_file_data = False
    file_to_save_results = None
    
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print_help()
    else:
        dir_a = sys.argv[1]
        dir_b = sys.argv[2]
        
        if len(sys.argv) == 4:
            if sys.argv[3] == "-a":
                compare_file_data = True
            else:
                print_help()
        elif len(sys.argv) == 5:
            if sys.argv[3] == "-s":
                file_to_save_results = open(sys.argv[4], "w")
            else:
                print_help()
        elif len(sys.argv) == 6:
            if sys.argv[3] == "-a" and sys.argv[4] == "-s":
                compare_file_data = True
                file_to_save_results = open(sys.argv[5], "w")
            elif sys.argv[5] == "-a" and sys.argv[3] == "-s":
                compare_file_data = True
                file_to_save_results = open(sys.argv[4], "w")
            else:
                print_help()
        elif len(sys.argv) > 6:
            print_help()
        
        print "Compare dirs %s and %s" % (dir_a, dir_b)
        print "Start compare"
        
        compare_dir_trees(dir_a, dir_b, compare_file_data, file_to_save_results)
        
        if file_to_save_results:
            file_to_save_results.close()
        
        print "End compare"
```

Comment: Why Python 2? There are vanishingly few circumstances where this is unavoidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code doesn't work

`for common_dir in dirs_cmp.common_dir:` fails, because `dirs_cmp` does not have a `common_dir`.

The correct attribute is `common_dirs`.  I'm going to assume this was some sort of copy-paste error (but that would be very odd since it was in the middle of the code!).

## Python 2.7 -vs- Python 3.x

Python 2.7 is "obsolete".  You should move to Python 3.x instead.
However, there may be times when you must use Python 2.7.
In these cases, it is much better to write code which will run equally well in both interpreters.  `__future__` is your friend here.

In Python 2.7, you can add at the top of your script:

`from __future__ import print_function`

and the Python 2.7 interpreter will then allow you to use Python 3.x style `print()` statements.

The Python 3.x interpreter will ignore this import, because the future is now.

## Don't exit

Avoid calling `sys.exit()` at all costs.  It unconditionally terminates your Python interpreter.

Why is that a problem?  If you ever want to call `print_help()` and then do more things, you can't.  For example, unit testing frameworks will call a function and compare the expected results with the actual results.  If that unit testing framework is written in Python, the unit testing framework abruptly stops.

A simple way around this is to move your mainline code into its own function.  After calling `print_help()`, follow that with `return` and the `main()` function will exit to its caller (such as the mainline code); the Python interpreter will not be terminated until the mainline code reaches the natural end of its execution.

```
def main(argv):
    ...
    if len(argv) < 3:
        print_help()
        return
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

As a benefit of the `return`, the rest of the code in the function doesn't need to be inside an `else:` block, making your code more "left leaning".

## Working with resources

You've got 3 `open()` statements and one `close()`.  If an exception occurs at any point in the code, the `close()` will not happen, and a file-system resource may be leaked.  It won't matter here, since you don't do any exception handling, and the file-system resource will be released by the Python interpreter, but it is better to get into good habits.

The `with` statement should be used to automatically close resources.
The resources will be closed at the end of the `with` block, regardless of whether the block is exited by

- reaching the end of the block,
- executing an early return statement, or
- an exception being raised.

## Nested function blocks

This is an advanced topic, but it simplifies your code a lot.

You keep recursing into a function with the parameters `compare_file_data, file_to_save_results` passed, unchanged.
The parameters aren't really part of the recursive function;
rather, they are just "configuration" variables.
Really, you want these parameters to be "global", but you've probably heard globals are bad to use.

Make them global, locally, with a nested function block.

```
def compare_dir_trees(dir1, dir2, compare_file_data, file_to_save_results):

   def show_diff_in_dir(dir_name, list_diff):
       ...

   def show_diff_in_files(dir_name, diff_files):
       ...

   def compare_dirs(dir1, dir2):
       ...

   compare_dirs(dir1, dir2)
```

Calling `compare_dir_trees()` will set the `compare_file_data, file_to_save_results` parameters for the entire execution of that function, which is composed of one statement: `compare_dirs(dir1, dir2)`.
That function has access to those parameters, as do the other `show_diff_in_` functions.

## Standard Output -vs- Output to File

`sys.stdout` is a file handle.
You can write to it just like you can write to `file_to_save_results`.
You just don't need to open or close it.

This means your `show_diff_in_` functions can be simplied to just writing to the passed in file handle, and not worry about choosing to print or write.
Actually, `print(..., file=file_to_save_results)` would be even simplier, as it takes care of the `"\n"` for you.

## Argument Parsing

If you look for the optional arguments `-a` and `-s <filename>` in `sys.argv`, and remove them if found, you will simplify argument parsing.
Specifically, you don't need to handle `-a -s <filename>` differently from `-s <filename> -a`!

## Reworked Code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import filecmp
import os.path
import sys

def print_help():
    print("Use : python cmp_dir.py <dir_1> <dir_2> [-a] [-s <file>]")
    print("dir_1 and dir_2 : directories to compare")
    print("-a : also compare data inside files")
    print("-s : save results inside <file>")

def compare_dir_trees(dir1, dir2, compare_file_data, output):

    def compare_dirs(dir1, dir2):
        dirs_cmp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    
        if dirs_cmp.left_only:
            print("files or subdirs only in %s : %s " % (dir1, dirs_cmp.left_only),
                  file=output)

        if dirs_cmp.right_only:
            print("files or subdirs only in %s : %s " % (dir2, dirs_cmp.right_only),
                  file=output)

        if compare_file_data and dirs_cmp.diff_files:
            print("different files in %s : %s " % (dir1, dirs_cmp.diff_files),
                  file=output)
        
        for common_dir in dirs_cmp.common_dirs:
            new_dir1 = os.path.join(dir1, common_dir)
            new_dir2 = os.path.join(dir2, common_dir)
            compare_dir(new_dir1, new_dir2)

    compare_dirs(dir1, dir2)

def main(argv):
    compare_file_data = False
    file_to_save_results = None

    if '-s' in argv:
        pos = argv.index('-s')
        if pos + 1 < len(argv):
            file_to_save_results = argv[pos + 1]
            del argv[pos:pos+2]

    if '-a' in argv:
        argv.remove('-a')
        compare_file_data = True

    if len(argv) != 3:
        print_help()
        return
    
    dir_a = argv[1]
    dir_b = argv[2]
    
    print("Compare dirs %s and %s" % (dir_a, dir_b))
    print("Start compare")

    if file_to_save_results:
        with open(file_to_save_results, "w") as file:
            compare_dir_trees(dir_a, dir_b, compare_file_data, file)
    else:
        compare_dir_trees(dir_a, dir_b, compare_file_data, sys.stdout)

    print("End compare")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

This works with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you really should stop using python 2, since it was sunset about 2 years ago. Outside of that, I'll try to keep my feedback somewhat balanced in regards to use of python 2, and I'll focus on what you request - ensuring that the code is "pythonic".

---

The way you're parsing arguments is clearly not pythonic. You say you don't have access to `argparse` [but I don't understand why you wouldn't](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html).

The way you're storing default arguments is also a bit odd; instead of defining

```py
    compare_file_data = False
    file_to_save_results = None
```

under an `if __name__ == "__main__":` you could just as well set the default in the functions themselves.

Finally, I don't like how you rely on side-effects in your functions. I think it's better that you modify strings or whatever other data structure you decide to use instead of having conditional print statements. If nothing else it would greatly help you with debugging.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer.
I don't understand how storing the default parameters in the function would help, since they still have to be retrieved from main, right?
Finally I don't understand why the code relies on a side-effect either? The message to be displayed is the same, either in the console or in a file (but maybe that just means that my variable names are poorly chosen and unclear)

Comment: For the default parameters, you'd generally do `def show_diff_in_dir(dir_name, list_diff, file_to_save_results=False):` and then you'd call on this with `show_diff_in_dir(dir_name, list_diff, file_to_save_results=True)` when necessary. As for the side-effects, I mean it's poor practices to `print` in your functions instead of just returning a string and then dealing with the printing in your compare function; `show_diff_in_files` would then be `diff_in_files`. There's nothing hugely wrong with your variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Python 2. You've tagged this `beginner`: beginners should not be learning deprecated technology.

Partially echo the feedback from @ades. Use `argparse`; use f-string interpolation instead of old-school percent-formatting. Don't have conditions on your `file_to_save_results`; instead unconditionally write to a file-like that defaults to `stdout`.

I find the direct `list` printing to be a little unsightly; consider using `join` instead.

Use `pathlib` instead of `os.path`.

I don't find the `Start compare` and `End compare` banners to be helpful and I think they can be dropped.

Add type hints.

### Suggested

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from filecmp import dircmp
from functools import partial
from pathlib import Path
from sys import stdout
from typing import TextIO


def parse_args() -> Namespace:
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='compare directories')
    parser.add_argument('dir_1', type=Path, help='first directory to compare')
    parser.add_argument('dir_2', type=Path, help='second directory to compare')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--compare-file-data', action='store_true', help='also compare data inside files')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--save-to', type=partial(open, mode='w'),
                        default=stdout, help='safe results inside SAVE_TO')
    return parser.parse_args()


def show_diff_in_dir(dir_name: Path, list_diff: list[str], save_to: TextIO) -> None:
    if list_diff:
        msg = f'files or subdirs only in {dir_name}: {", ".join(list_diff)}'
        print(msg, file=save_to)


def show_diff_in_files(dir_name: Path, diff_files: list[str], save_to: TextIO) -> None:
    print(f'different files in {dir_name}: {", ".join(diff_files)}', file=save_to)


def compare_dir_trees(dir_1: Path, dir_2: Path, compare_file_data: bool, save_to: TextIO) -> None:
    dirs_cmp = dircmp(dir_1, dir_2)
    show_diff_in_dir(dir_1, dirs_cmp.left_only, save_to)
    show_diff_in_dir(dir_2, dirs_cmp.right_only, save_to)

    if compare_file_data and dirs_cmp.diff_files:
        show_diff_in_files(dir_1, dirs_cmp.diff_files, save_to)

    for common_dir in dirs_cmp.common_dirs:
        compare_dir_trees(dir_1 / common_dir, dir_2 / common_dir, compare_file_data, save_to)


def main() -> None:
    args = parse_args()
    print(f'Compare dirs {args.dir_1} and {args.dir_2}')
    compare_dir_trees(**args.__dict__)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll try not to repeat existing answers. Let's first note two things:

- When someone (you included) reads the `if` statements at the top of `compare_dir_trees`, they might not be sure whether some of them were meant to be `elif`s. An important part of clean code is to make what's right *obviously* right.
- Apart from the value of `msg`, `show_diff_in_dir` and `show_diff_in_files` currently do the same thing.

Let's refactor the aforementioned functions to reduce repetition and the number of explicit `if` statements in `compare_dir_trees`. I start by introducing a helper function:

```
def show_diff(dir_name, prefix, last_msg_arg, file_to_save_results):
    if not last_msg_arg: return
    msg = "%s %s: %s" % (prefix, dir_name, last_msg_arg)
    # Some answers advised changing behaviour below,
    # so calls to show_diff return its result, which is currently None
    if file_to_save_results:
        file_to_save_results.write(msg + "\n")
    else:
        print msg

def show_diff_in_dir(dir_name, list_diff, file_to_save_results):
    return show_diff(dir_name, "files or subdirs only in", list_diff, file_to_save_results)

def show_diff_in_files(dir_name, diff_files, file_to_save_results):
    return show_diff(dir_name, "different files in", diff_files, file_to_save_results)

def compare_dir_trees(dir1, dir2, compare_file_data, file_to_save_results):
    dirs_cmp = filecmp.dircmp(dir1, dir2)
    show_diff_in_dir(dir1, dirs_cmp.left_only, file_to_save_results)
    show_diff_in_dir(dir2, dirs_cmp.right_only, file_to_save_results)
    if compare_file_data:
        show_diff_in_files(dir1, dirs_cmp.diff_files, file_to_save_results)
    # Rest of function
```

The first comment above (which you shouldn't keep!) explains how two `return`s make the code I've suggested more maintainable.

Several answers have advised you not to use Python 2.7. I realize you might be stuck with it, but if you one day can use at least 3.4 I can make [another suggestion](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use): replace `os.path.join(dir1, common_dir)` with `pathlib.Path(dir1)/common_dir`, and similarly with `dir2`. This allows a nice improvement to the `for` loop in `compare_dir_trees`.